# Tesseract and dylib on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, tesseract, dylib

I just installed `imagemagick` and `tesseract` through `brew`, everything went well. When I try `tesseract -l eng decrypted.png output`, though, I get the following error:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tesseract
  Reason: Incompatible library version: tesseract requires version 32.0.0 or later, but libpng15.15.dylib provides version 29.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I searched *everywhere* but I couldn't find any place where it is explained how to update that dynamic library to version 32 (or higher). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by cleaning my installation of both the softwares and re-installing them through `brew`. Mind that if there is some linking problem, you have to execute `brew link --overwrite tesseract` to solve them.